# jQuery to remove parents of a nested LI only if the parents do not have additional children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to to implement a way for users to delete a nested list item, removing that item from the DOM, and then remove all parents which do not have additional children aside from the LI being removed. I also do not want that LI to be removed if the one the user tries to delete has children. My javascript is not working properly. It deletes all parents whether or not they have children.

Here is the jsfiddle, I want it so that if the X is clicked, I want to remove the LI's 'd' and 'c', leaving 'b' and 'e' intact:
jsfiddle.net/2t0xrv8c/2

My javascript is:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-from-heading', function() {
    var articleId = $(this).closest('.c-cont').attr("data-article");
    var crumbId = $(this).closest('li').attr("heading");

    //if the current LI doesn't have children, let's delete it, along with all parents that don't have children 
    if( !$(this).closest('li').children('li').length ){
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass('assigned');          

        //for each parent li
        $(this).parents('li').each(function( index ) {  
            // check to see if it has children LI's         
            if( !$(this).children('li').length ){
                $(this).remove();
            }
            $(this).remove();
        });

    }else{
        //The current LI has children, so let's just remove the delete button
        $(this).closest('li').removeClass('assigned');
        $(this).remove();           
    }
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="crumb-cont" tree="0"><h5>NOTES</h5>
        <ul>
            <li heading="40845" parent="0">
                <div class="">METHODS </div>
                <ul>
                    <li heading="41896" parent="40845">
                       <div class="">Immune cell types</div>
                <ul>
                    <li heading="41356" parent="41896" class="assigned">
                        <div>1. B cell analyses ***KEEPER review of this section done<span class="delete-from-heading tooltip-top" title="Remove article from this heading"></span></div>
                        <ul>
                             <li heading="41358" parent="41356">
                                  <div>Assays using different in vitro methods of manipulating B cells</div>
                                  <ul>
                                       <li heading="41360" parent="41358" class="assigned">
                                           <div>Combination of methods or applicable to multiple methods<span class="delete-from-heading tooltip-top" title="Remove article from this heading"></span></div>
                                       </li>
                                  </ul>
                              </li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
             </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: You description is a total mess! Please be clear.

Comment: HTML snippet..........

Comment: can you add your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2t0xrv8c/2/   In the jsfiddle, if the X is clicked, I want it to remove the LI's 'd' and 'c', leaving 'b' and 'e' intact.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$(this).parents('li');
$(this).parent('li');
```

instead of

```
$(this).closest('li')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 $('li').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
if($(this).find('ul').length == 0)
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Tested it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2t0xrv8c/1/)

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle with my code. jsfiddle.net/2t0xrv8c/2  I want it so that if the X is clicked, the LI's 'd' and 'c' are removed, leaving 'b' and 'e' intact.